# Array to string conversion in php in data loading

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

```
    <?php

$serverName = "RAHULTCO-PC\MANTRA2005";
$url1=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 1; URL=$url1");
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"PayTime", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"Mantra123");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
$con1 = $con1=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gps_db');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:sa');
$sql = "SELECT TOP 10 CardNO FROM dbo.tmpDmpTerminalData order by In_Out_Time desc ";
/*$sql = "SELECT [CardNO]
  FROM [PayTime].[dbo].[tmpDmpTerminalData] WHERE (IPaddress = '172.23.42.141' AND In_Out_Time >= '$date')";*/

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Make the first (and in this case, only) row of the result set available for reading.
if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Get the row fields. Field indeces start at 0 and must be retrieved in order.
// Retrieving row fields by name is not supported by sqlsrv_get_field.

if ($conn){
  $items = array();
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      $items[] = $row;

}
   print_r($items);
} 

else{
  echo "connection failed.<br />";
  die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "gps_db";


$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


if ($con) {
    echo "Connected";
}
    $query = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `gps_gatepassmaster` WHERE `punch_id` IN (".implode(',',$items).")";
    $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if ($run == TRUE){
      ?>
      <table border="1" width="80%" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td>user_id</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data['user_id'];?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
        }
         ?></table><?php
```

> Output of array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115293 ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [CardNO] => 100087 ) [2] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115293 ) [3]
>   => Array ( [CardNO] => 100087 ) [4] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115293 ) [5] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115163 ) [6] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115201
>   ) [7] => Array ( [CardNO] => 115293 ) [8] => Array ( [CardNO] =>
>   115163 ) )

Data is not loading giving error

> "Array to string conversion in
>   D:\wamp\www\reports_vinay\connect_to_multiple.php on line 54".

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh `sqlsrv_connect()` suggest that he's on sql server

Comment: I've no idea of what line 54 contains...

Comment: Please in future only select tags that are relevant to you problem, don't spam other tags

Answer (score 0):

`implode` only works with arrays with a single dimension, you're passing a multi dimensional one. You should be able to solve it by *just* putting the card numbers into the `$items` array instead of the entire row.

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $items[] = $row['CardNO'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($conn){
  $items = array();
  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $items[] = $row;

}
print_r($items);
}
```

this means that your `$items` is a associative array and on line no 54.
that is `WHERE`punch_id`IN (".implode(',',$items).")";` here you are using it as simple array.

Thats the problem.

change `$items[] = $row;` to  `$items[] = $row['CardNO'];`